# How can I manage the location of my application icon in android

Tags: android

After installing my application, I want to locate the application icon into my folder, not directly appear at the main menu .
How can i write to change it after app installed .

Comment: Don't you think that it's the application user's decision?.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.

Your application shouldn't interfere with how it is shown in the application launcher. This sort of thing should be the user's decision, not the developer's.

Comment: In fact, I would be surprised if Android permissions allowed an application to do this at all. The location of the application's icon (if it has one!) seems like it'd probably belong to the launcher, not to the application.

Comment: I konw your meanings.now I will develop an application .
it's function is to download  an application from android market then
this appliction installing will be added my application folder not in main menu,I want to manage certain applications what are the same categoris .eg: I want to develop an application about educations.